# Splitting of ideal in PID $Z[\alpha]$ into prime ideals, and a generalization

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ be a PID, where $\alpha$ is an algebraic integer. I am wondering if the following proof shows that a for a prime $p$, the ideal $(p)$ splits into a product of distinct prime ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ if and only if $m_\alpha(X)$ splits modulo $p$, where $m_\alpha$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$.

**Proof**$\quad$ We have the isomorphism $$ \frac{\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]}{(p)}\cong\frac{\mathbb{F}_p[X]}{(m_\alpha(X))}.$$ If $(p)$ splits into prime ideals $(p)=\mathfrak{p}_1\mathfrak{p}_2\cdots\mathfrak{p}_n$, since we are in a PID, they are all pairwise comaximal. Hence we apply the Chinese remainder theorem to get $$\frac{\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]}{(p)}\cong\frac{\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]}{\mathfrak{p}_1}\times \frac{\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]}{\mathfrak{p}_2}\times\cdots\times \frac{\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]}{\mathfrak{p}_n}.$$ Since $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ is a PID, the elements in the direct product are fields. Hence if we compose with the projection map $$\mathbb{F}_p[X]\rightarrow\frac{\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]}{(p)}\rightarrow \frac{\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]}{\mathfrak{p}_k},$$
the kernel is a prime ideal. The intersection of all such prime ideals is the ideal $(m_\alpha(X))$, by our initial isomorphism. Moreover, since we are in a PID, all such prime ideals are pairwise comaximal, so their intersection is their product. Thus, we have decomposed $(m_\alpha(X))$ into a product of prime ideals, namely the kernels of the above map for all $k$. I believe we can do a similar argument to prove the reverse direction.

I was first wondering if this proof is correct. Moreover, if it is, is there a generalization to non-PIDs? Since it is heavily reliant on the Chinese remainder theorem, I am not sure how to do it differently, for a general UFD, for example.

Comment: You say "a product of prime ideals" but in your argument you use that they are distinct, i.e. that no prime ideal occurs with multiplicity greater than $1$; did you intend to assume this? What is your definition of "splits modulo $p$"? Conventionally this means "splits into linear factors, not necessarily distinct" and that's a much stronger condition than the condition that $(p)$ factors into prime ideals, which is always true.